# Website search functionality with PHP

Tags: php, html, search, mysqli

I'm a beginner and I try to make an agriculture application, to gain some experience, and to try something advanced. But I can't figure out how to make searches within my application. I have:

```
- 4 select html elements
- 5 search boxes
```

For space reasons, I'll write just 3/14 columns for the html elements.

**HTML code:**

```
<form>
    <!-- makes the global filter based on all the data from db -->
    <select id="select1" name="select1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="code">Code</option>
        <option value="land">Land</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
    </select><br/>

    <!-- makes a filter for a html column, based on a db column -->
    <select id="select2" name="select2" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All parcels</option>
        <option value="P1">P1</option>
        <option value="P2">P2</option>
        <option value="P3">P3</option>
    </select>

    <!-- search boxes to filter 5 html columns -->
    <input type="search" id="search1" name="search2">
    <input type="search" id="search2" name="search2">
    <input type="search" id="search3" name="search3">
    <input type="search" id="search4" name="search4">

    <!-- same as the previous select menu, just this is for another html column -->
    <select id="select3" name="select3" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="MO">MO</option>
        <option value="MA">MA</option>
        <option value="ME">ME</option>
    </select>

    <!-- the 5th search box -->
    <input type="search" id="search5" name="search5">

    <!-- renders the data from db according to the selections made by the user or search terms -->
    <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th id="code">Code</th>
            <th id="land">Land</th>
            <th id="name">Name</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <?php
                require 'config.php'; # login to database
                # ---- QUERY ----
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- this displays in the page as many rows as the user selects -->
    <select name="select4" id="select4" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP code:** I just put this block of code instead of "# ---- QUERY ----" from above, to populate the html columns within the page:

```
if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
    $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
    switch($select1){
        case 'code':
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `code`='code'");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr class="action">
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
                    <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                </tr> <?php
            }
        break; # some more cases follows
    } # end switch($select1)
} # end if(isset($_POST['select1']))
elseif(isset($_POST['select2'])){
    $select2 = $_POST['select2'];
    switch($select2){
        case P1:
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `parcel` LIKE '%P1%'");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr class="action">
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
                    <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                </tr> <?php
            }
        break; # some more cases here
    } # end switch($select2)
} # end if(isset$_POST['select2'])
elseif(isset($_POST['search1'])){
    $search1 = $_POST['search1'];
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name` LIKE '%search1%'");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr> <?php
    }
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['search1']))
elseif(isset($_POST['search2'])){
    $search2 = $_POST['search2'];
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `cont_ref_a` LIKE '%search2%'");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr> <?php
    }
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['search2']))
elseif(isset($_POST['search3'])){
    $search3 = $_POST['search3'];
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `owner` LIKE '%search3%'");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr> <?php
    }
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['search3']))
elseif(isset($_POST['search4'])){
    $search4 = $_POST['search4'];
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `block` LIKE '%search4%'");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr> <?php
    }
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['search4']))
elseif(isset($_POST['select3'])){
    $select3 = $_POST['select3'];
    switch($select3){
        case 'T1':
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `zone`='T1'");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr class="action">
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
                    <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                </tr> <?php
            }
        break; # end case 'T1', more cases follows
    } # end switch($select3)
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['select3']))
elseif (isset($_POST['search5'])){
    $search5 = $_POST['search5'];
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `s_a` LIKE '%search5%'");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr><?php
    }
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['search5']))
elseif(isset($_POST['select1'])){
    $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
    switch($select1){
        case 'code':
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr class="action">
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        break; # end case 'code', more cases follows
    } # end switch($select1)
} # end elseif(isset($_POST[select1]))
elseif(isset($_POST['select4'])){
    $select4 = $_POST['select4'];
    switch($select4){
        case 1:
            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1");
            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr class="action">
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
                    <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
                    <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                </tr><?php
            }
        break; # end case 1, more cases follows
    } # end switch($select4)
} # end elseif(isset($_POST['select4'])))
else { # if noone of the select menus or search boxes where filled, then just render all the data from db to the page
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <tr class="action">
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td id="td"><?php echo $row['land'];?></td>
            <td id="td2"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        </tr><?php
    }
} # end php script
```

Sorry for this post beeing so long, but I tried to express as better as I can. The problem is that when I select one option from a select menu, or I enter a term to search, nothing is displayed. I don't care for now if something is missing in my code when comes about security, I just want to make this app work. Any help? Thanks a lot!

---

LE: I finally found the fix for my problem (and I will write it here so that any other persons that will search for this type of problems, to have an answer (I'll write a trivial example)):

**For search-boxes:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="search1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr><?php
            if(isset($_POST['search1'])){
                $search1 = $_POST['search1'];
                if(!empty($_POST['search1'])){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE fname LIKE '%$search1%'";
                    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                        </tr><?php
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblName";
                $stmt = $db->query($sql);
                while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

**For select-menus:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="select1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="fname">First Name</option>
        <option value="lname">Last Name</option>
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr><?php
            if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
                $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
                if(!empty($_POST['select1'])){
                    switch($select1){
                        case 'fname':
                            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
                            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                                </tr><?php
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'lname':
                            $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
                            while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                                </tr><?php
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
                while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }?>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I assume you have a named element called `select1`? It's nowhere in your question and your entire query is dependant on it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm a bit tired! Yes, I have the first select menu, whose name is "select1". This is the global selection, based on the html columns. Eg: If the user selects "Code" then it will be returned all the data from the column `data` from my db; etc.

Comment: Then, take my suggestion. Get some sleep, and get back to it with a fresh head. Believe me, it works and you'll probably end up thanking me for it. A tired head makes for tired code ;-)

Comment: also, you will want to refine this so that you really are writing your query and execution once and just running it with variables that are received from the form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is incomplete. The way it is written, many of your search options won't work. I would try selecting select2 and P1. That should work.

But there is potentially a bug in all of your IF statements. You shouldn't just test if a $_POST variable is set, you should make sure it's not NULL or zero length (strlen($var) > 0). Post variables can be "set" but still not have been submitted with actual data.

I would removed everything in your example that isn't related to select2 and see if you can get it to work in a much simpler format.

And of course smashing all of your SQL and PHP code in with a bunch of HTML is a bad idea, but that's not part of the question.

Comment: This is the problem. I tried the example you gave, for one select menu and one search box, and it worked. But when it cames to work entirely as app, it fails. And it makes me so angry, cause I feel something 'small' makes the difference from not working to the opposite.